# Select child record in relation two tables

Tags: entity-framework, linq

What is the best solutions to retrieve records from child table in relation?

I cannot include the solution file in this question.

Model

```
[Table("Tbl_DefaultValue")]
public class DefaultValue
{
    [Key]
    public int DefaultValue_ID { get; set; }
    public string DefaultVal_Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DefaultValue_Det> DefaultValue_Det { get; set; }

}

[Table("Tbl_DefaultValue_Det")]
public class DefaultValue_Det
{
    [Key]
    public int DefaultValue_Det_ID { get; set; }
    public int DefaultValue_ID { get; set; }
    public string DefaultValue_Value { get; set; }
   public virtual DefaultValue DefaultValue { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
driverdt.TypeList = 
  new SelectList(db.DefaultValue_Det
   .Where(a => a.DefaultValue_ID == db.DefaultValue
      .Where(d => d.DefaultVal_Name == "marid")
       .Max(b=>b.DefaultValue_ID)), "DefaultValue_Det_ID", "DefaultValue_Value");
   return View( driverdt);
```

Comment: Confusing wording, but if you want the child use an Include() like: new SelectList(db.DefaultValue_Det.Include(a => a.DefaultValue).Where(...

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-populate collection `DefaultValue_Det` using `FetchMany`:

```
driverdt.TypeList = 
  new SelectList(db.DefaultValue_Det
   .Where(a => a.DefaultValue_ID == db.DefaultValue
      .Where(d => d.DefaultVal_Name == "marid")
       .Max(b=>b.DefaultValue_ID))
       .FetchMany(x => x.DefaultValue_Det)
, "DefaultValue_Det_ID", "DefaultValue_Value");
```